# Android MultiColumn ListView showing records with sorting function

Tags: android

**Context**
   **
  I am new to Android.I m having Error at getView method when i set text to holder.column1.other columns works fine.i comment that both lines.Here my code--
   **
    **MulticolumnListViewCustomAdapter.java**

```
public class MulticolumnListViewCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Feedback>{

    public static final String TAG = MulticolumnListViewCustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();


    private ArrayList<Feedback> data;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int layoutResource;

    final public static int SORT_CUST_NAME_ASCENDING = 1;
    final public static int SORT_CUST_NAME_DESCENDING = 2;
    final public static int SORT_CUST_EMAIL_ASCENDING = 3;
    final public static int SORT_CUST_EMAIL_DESCENDING = 4;
    final public static int SORT_CUST_SEX_ASCENDING = 5;
    final public static int SORT_CUST_SEX_DESCENDING = 6;
    final public static int SORT_CUST_FEEDTYPE_ASCENDING = 7;
    final public static int SORT_CUST_FEEDTYPE_DESCENDING = 8;
    final public static int SORT_CUST_FEEDBACK_ASCENDING = 9;
    final public static int SORT_CUST_FEEDBACK_DESCENDING = 10;

    private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> checkedList = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    private CheckBox checkAllBox;
    private Boolean cancelSetCheckedAll = false;

    public MulticolumnListViewCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Feedback> data, CheckBox checkAllBox, int sortMode) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, data);
        constructor(context, textViewResourceId, data, checkAllBox, (sortMode<1||sortMode>10)?SORT_CUST_NAME_ASCENDING:sortMode);
    }
    public MulticolumnListViewCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Feedback> data, CheckBox checkAllBox) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, data);
        constructor(context, textViewResourceId, data, checkAllBox, SORT_CUST_NAME_ASCENDING);
    }    
    public void constructor(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Feedback> data, CheckBox checkAllBox, int sortMode) {
        this.checkAllBox = checkAllBox;
        this.data = data;
        switch(sortMode) {
        default:
        case SORT_CUST_NAME_ASCENDING: 
            sortByCustNameAscending(false);
            break;
        case SORT_CUST_NAME_DESCENDING: 
            sortByCustNameDescending(false);
            break;
        case SORT_CUST_EMAIL_ASCENDING: 
            sortByCustEmailAscending(false);
            break;
        case SORT_CUST_EMAIL_DESCENDING: 
            sortByCustEmailDescending(false);
            break;
        case SORT_CUST_SEX_ASCENDING: 
            sortByCustSexAscending(false);
            break;
        case SORT_CUST_SEX_DESCENDING: 
            sortByCustSexDescending(false);
            break;
        case SORT_CUST_FEEDTYPE_ASCENDING: 
            sortByCustFeedTypeAscending(false);
            break;
        case SORT_CUST_FEEDTYPE_DESCENDING: 
            sortByCustFeedTypeDescending(false);
            break;
        case SORT_CUST_FEEDBACK_ASCENDING: 
            sortByCustFeedbackAscending(false);
            break;
        case SORT_CUST_FEEDBACK_DESCENDING: 
            sortByCustFeedbackDescending(false);
            break;
    }
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.layoutResource = textViewResourceId;
        checkAllBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!cancelSetCheckedAll)setCheckedAll(isChecked); else cancelSetCheckedAll=false;
            }
        });
    }
    public void setCheckedAll(Boolean state) {
        checkedList.clear();
        for (Feedback item : this.data) {
            checkedList.put(Integer.valueOf(item.getListId()), state);
        }
        refreshList(true);
    }

    public void sortByCustNameAscending(Boolean refreshList) {
        this.data = SortFeedbackResults.sortByCustNameAscending(this.data);
        refreshList(refreshList);
    }
    public void sortByCustNameDescending(Boolean refreshList) {
        this.data = SortFeedbackResults.sortByCustNameDescending(this.data);
        refreshList(refreshList);
    }
    public void sortByCustEmailAscending(Boolean refreshList) {
        this.data = SortFeedbackResults.sortByCustEmailAscending(this.data);
        refreshList(refreshList);
    }
    public void sortByCustEmailDescending(Boolean refreshList) {
        this.data = SortFeedbackResults.sortByCustEmailDescending(this.data);
        refreshList(refreshList);
    }

    public void sortByCustSexAscending(Boolean refreshList) {
        this.data = SortFeedbackResults.sortByCustSexAscending(this.data);
        refreshList(refreshList);
    }
    public void sortByCustSexDescending(Boolean refreshList) {
        this.data = SortFeedbackResults.sortByCustSexDescending(this.data);
        refreshList(refreshList);
    }
    public void sortByCustFeedTypeAscending(Boolean refreshList) {
        this.data = SortFeedbackResults.sortByCustFeedTypeAscending(this.data);
        refreshList(refreshList);
    }
    public void sortByCustFeedTypeDescending(Boolean refreshList) {
        this.data = SortFeedbackResults.sortByCustFeedTypeDescending(this.data);
        refreshList(refreshList);
    }

    public void sortByCustFeedbackAscending(Boolean refreshList) {
            this.data = SortFeedbackResults.sortByCustFeedbackAscending(this.data);
            refreshList(refreshList);
        }
    public void sortByCustFeedbackDescending(Boolean refreshList) {
            this.data = SortFeedbackResults.sortByCustFeedbackDescending(this.data);
            refreshList(refreshList);
    }
    public void sortByCustNameAscending() {
        sortByCustNameAscending(true);
    }
    public void sortByCustNameDescending() {
        sortByCustNameDescending(true);
    }
    public void sortByCustEmailAscending() {
        sortByCustEmailAscending(true);
    }
    public void sortByCustEmailDescending() {
        sortByCustEmailDescending(true);
    }
    public void sortByCustSexAscending() {
        sortByCustSexAscending(true);
    }
    public void sortByCustSexDescending() {
        sortByCustSexDescending(true);
    }
    public void sortByCustFeedTypeAscending() {
        sortByCustFeedTypeAscending(true);
    }
    public void sortByCustFeedTypeDescending() {
        sortByCustFeedTypeDescending(true);
    }
    public void sortByCustFeedbackAscending() {
        sortByCustFeedbackAscending(true);
    }
    public void sortByCustFeedbackDescending() {
        sortByCustFeedbackDescending(true);
    }


    public void refreshList(Boolean really) {
        if (really) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final ViewHolder holder;
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null){

             v = mInflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);

             holder = new ViewHolder();

             holder.id = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.custid);
             holder.column1 = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.column1);
             holder.column2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.column2);
             holder.column3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.column3);
             holder.column4 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.column4);
             holder.column5 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.column5);
             holder.column6 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.column6);
             holder.column7 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.column7);

             holder.column1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    int id = Integer.valueOf((String) holder.id.getText());
                    checkedList.remove(id);
                    checkedList.put(id, isChecked);

                    if(isChecked==false&&checkAllBox.isChecked()){cancelSetCheckedAll=true;checkAllBox.setChecked(false);}
                }
            });

             v.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }

        Feedback c = data.get(position);
        if(c != null){

            //holder.id.setText(c.getListId());
            //holder.id.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            int id = Integer.valueOf(c.getListId());
            if(checkedList.containsKey(id)){
                holder.column1.setChecked(checkedList.get(id));
            }else{
                holder.column1.setChecked(false);
            }
            holder.column1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.column2.setText(c.getName());
            holder.column2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.column3.setText(c.getEmail());
            holder.column3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.column4.setText(c.getSex());
            holder.column4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.column5.setText(c.getFeedbackType());
            holder.column5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.column6.setText(c.getFeedback());
            holder.column6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.column7.setText(c.getEmailRes());
            holder.column7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }else{

            holder.id.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.column1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.column2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.column3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.column4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.column5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.column6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return v;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView id;
        CheckBox column1;
        TextView column2;
        TextView column3;
        TextView column4;
        TextView column5;
        TextView column6;
        TextView column7;
    }

    private static class SortFeedbackResults {

        public static ArrayList<Feedback> sortByCustNameAscending(ArrayList<Feedback> list){
            Collections.sort(list, new SortFeedbackResultsByCustNameAscending());
            return list;
        }
        private static class SortFeedbackResultsByCustNameAscending implements Comparator<Feedback>{
            public int compare(Feedback lhs, Feedback rhs) {
                if(lhs.getName().equals(rhs.getName())){
                    return lhs.getEmail().compareTo(rhs.getEmail());
                }
                return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
            }
        }

        public static ArrayList<Feedback> sortByCustNameDescending(ArrayList<Feedback> list){
            Collections.sort(list, new SortFeedbackResultsByCustNameDescending());
            return list;
        }
        private static class SortFeedbackResultsByCustNameDescending implements Comparator<Feedback>{

            public int compare(Feedback lhs, Feedback rhs) {
                if(lhs.getName().equals(rhs.getName())){
                    return lhs.getEmail().compareTo(rhs.getEmail());
                }
                int result = lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
                return (result>0)?-result:-0-result;
            }
        }


        public static ArrayList<Feedback> sortByCustEmailAscending(ArrayList<Feedback> list){
            Collections.sort(list, new SortFeedbackResultsByCustEmailAscending());
            return list;
        }
        private static class SortFeedbackResultsByCustEmailAscending implements Comparator<Feedback>{
            public int compare(Feedback lhs, Feedback rhs) {

                    return lhs.getEmail().compareTo(rhs.getEmail());
            }
        }

        public static ArrayList<Feedback> sortByCustEmailDescending(ArrayList<Feedback> list){
            Collections.sort(list, new SortFeedbackResultsByCustEmailDescending());
            return list;
        }
        private static class SortFeedbackResultsByCustEmailDescending implements Comparator<Feedback>{

            public int compare(Feedback lhs, Feedback rhs) {

                    int result = lhs.getEmail().compareTo(rhs.getEmail());

                return (result>0)?-result:-0-result;
            }
        }


        public static ArrayList<Feedback> sortByCustSexAscending(ArrayList<Feedback> list){
            Collections.sort(list, new SortFeedbackResultsByCustSexAscending());
            return list;
        }
        private static class SortFeedbackResultsByCustSexAscending implements Comparator<Feedback>{
            public int compare(Feedback lhs, Feedback rhs) {
                if(lhs.getSex().equals(rhs.getSex())){
                    return lhs.getEmail().compareTo(rhs.getEmail());
                }
                return lhs.getSex().compareTo(rhs.getSex());
            }
        }

        public static ArrayList<Feedback> sortByCustSexDescending(ArrayList<Feedback> list){
            Collections.sort(list, new SortFeedbackResultsByCustSexDescending());
            return list;
        }
        private static class SortFeedbackResultsByCustSexDescending implements Comparator<Feedback>{

            public int compare(Feedback lhs, Feedback rhs) {
                if(lhs.getSex().equals(rhs.getSex())){
                    return lhs.getEmail().compareTo(rhs.getEmail());
                }
                int result = lhs.getSex().compareTo(rhs.getSex());
                return (result>0)?-result:-0-result;
            }
        }


        public static ArrayList<Feedback> sortByCustFeedTypeAscending(ArrayList<Feedback> list){
            Collections.sort(list, new SortFeedbackResultsByCustFeedTypeAscending());
            return list;
        }
        private static class SortFeedbackResultsByCustFeedTypeAscending implements Comparator<Feedback>{
            public int compare(Feedback lhs, Feedback rhs) {
                if(lhs.getFeedbackType().equals(rhs.getFeedbackType())){
                    return lhs.getEmail().compareTo(rhs.getEmail());
                }
                return lhs.getFeedbackType().compareTo(rhs.getFeedbackType());
            }
        }

        public static ArrayList<Feedback> sortByCustFeedTypeDescending(ArrayList<Feedback> list){
            Collections.sort(list, new SortFeedbackResultsByCustFeedTypeDescending());
            return list;
        }
        private static class SortFeedbackResultsByCustFeedTypeDescending implements Comparator<Feedback>{

            public int compare(Feedback lhs, Feedback rhs) {
                if(lhs.getFeedbackType().equals(rhs.getFeedbackType())){
                    return lhs.getEmail().compareTo(rhs.getEmail());
                }
                int result = lhs.getFeedbackType().compareTo(rhs.getFeedbackType());
                return (result>0)?-result:-0-result;
            }
        }


        public static ArrayList<Feedback> sortByCustFeedbackAscending(ArrayList<Feedback> list){
            Collections.sort(list, new SortFeedbackResultsByCustFeedbackAscending());
            return list;
        }
        private static class SortFeedbackResultsByCustFeedbackAscending implements Comparator<Feedback>{
            public int compare(Feedback lhs, Feedback rhs) {
                if(lhs.getFeedback().equals(rhs.getFeedback())){
                    return lhs.getEmail().compareTo(rhs.getEmail());
                }
                return lhs.getFeedback().compareTo(rhs.getFeedback());
            }
        }

        public static ArrayList<Feedback> sortByCustFeedbackDescending(ArrayList<Feedback> list){
            Collections.sort(list, new SortFeedbackResultsByCustFeedbackDescending());
            return list;
        }
        private static class SortFeedbackResultsByCustFeedbackDescending implements Comparator<Feedback>{

            public int compare(Feedback lhs, Feedback rhs) {
                if(lhs.getFeedback().equals(rhs.getFeedback())){
                    return lhs.getEmail().compareTo(rhs.getEmail());
                }
                int result = lhs.getFeedback().compareTo(rhs.getFeedback());
                return (result>0)?-result:-0-result;
            }
        }

    }

}


**MainActivity----**

public class MulticolumnListViewTest extends Activity {

    private Boolean column2State = true;
    private Boolean column3State = true;
    private Boolean column4State = true;
    private Boolean column5State = true;
    private Boolean column6State = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multicolumn_list_view_test);

        this.getApplicationContext();
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        ArrayList<Feedback> myListData = new ArrayList<Feedback>();

        for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
            Feedback feedback = new Feedback();
            String iString = Integer.toString(i);
            feedback.setName("Name"+i);
            feedback.setEmail("Email"+i);
            feedback.setSex("Sex"+i);
            feedback.setFeedbackType("FeedType"+i);
            feedback.setFeedback("Feedback"+i);
            feedback.setEmailRes("Res"+i);
            feedback.setListId(iString);

            myListData.add(feedback);
        }

        final MulticolumnListViewCustomAdapter multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter = new MulticolumnListViewCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_multicolumn_list_view_test, myListData, (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.column1));
        list.setAdapter(multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter);

        final LinearLayout column2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.column2_container);
        final LinearLayout column3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.column3_container);
        final LinearLayout column4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.column4_container);
        final LinearLayout column5 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.column5_container);
        final LinearLayout column6 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.column6_container);
        final TextView column2Arrow = (TextView)column2.getChildAt(1);
        final TextView column3Arrow = (TextView)column3.getChildAt(1);
        final TextView column4Arrow = (TextView)column4.getChildAt(1);
        final TextView column5Arrow = (TextView)column5.getChildAt(1);
        final TextView column6Arrow = (TextView)column6.getChildAt(1);
        column2.setOnTouchListener(columnContainerOnTouchListener(column2));
        column3.setOnTouchListener(columnContainerOnTouchListener(column3));
        column4.setOnTouchListener(columnContainerOnTouchListener(column4));
        column5.setOnTouchListener(columnContainerOnTouchListener(column5));
        column6.setOnTouchListener(columnContainerOnTouchListener(column6));

        column2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("COLUMN 2 CLICK");
                if(column2State){
                    column2State = false;
                    column2Arrow.setText(R.string.solid_down);
                    column3Arrow.setText("");
                    column4Arrow.setText("");
                    column5Arrow.setText("");
                    column6Arrow.setText("");
                    multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter.sortByCustNameDescending();
                }else{
                    column2State = true;
                    column3Arrow.setText("");
                    column4Arrow.setText("");
                    column5Arrow.setText("");
                    column6Arrow.setText("");
                    multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter.sortByCustNameAscending();
                }
            }
        });

        column3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("COLUMN 3 CLICK");
                if(column3State){
                    column3State = false;
                    column3Arrow.setText(R.string.solid_down);
                    column2Arrow.setText("");
                    column4Arrow.setText("");
                    column5Arrow.setText("");
                    column6Arrow.setText("");
                    multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter.sortByCustEmailDescending();
                }else{
                    column3State = true;
                    column2Arrow.setText("");
                    column4Arrow.setText("");
                    column5Arrow.setText("");
                    column6Arrow.setText("");
                    multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter.sortByCustEmailAscending();
                }

            }
        });

        column4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("COLUMN 4 CLICK");
                if(column4State){
                    column4State = false;
                    column4Arrow.setText(R.string.solid_down);
                    column3Arrow.setText("");
                    column2Arrow.setText("");
                    column5Arrow.setText("");
                    column6Arrow.setText("");
                    multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter.sortByCustSexDescending();
                }else{
                    column4State = true;
                    column3Arrow.setText("");
                    column2Arrow.setText("");
                    column5Arrow.setText("");
                    column6Arrow.setText("");
                    multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter.sortByCustSexAscending();
                }

            }
        });

        column5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("COLUMN 5 CLICK");
                if(column5State){
                    column5State = false;
                    column5Arrow.setText(R.string.solid_down);
                    column3Arrow.setText("");
                    column4Arrow.setText("");
                    column2Arrow.setText("");
                    column6Arrow.setText("");
                    multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter.sortByCustFeedTypeDescending();
                }else{
                    column5State = true;
                    column3Arrow.setText("");
                    column4Arrow.setText("");
                    column2Arrow.setText("");
                    column6Arrow.setText("");
                    multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter.sortByCustFeedTypeAscending();
                }

            }
        });

        column6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("COLUMN 2 CLICK");
                if(column6State){
                    column6State = false;
                    column6Arrow.setText(R.string.solid_down);
                    column3Arrow.setText("");
                    column4Arrow.setText("");
                    column5Arrow.setText("");
                    column2Arrow.setText("");
                    multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter.sortByCustFeedbackDescending();
                }else{
                    column6State = true;
                    column3Arrow.setText("");
                    column4Arrow.setText("");
                    column5Arrow.setText("");
                    column2Arrow.setText("");
                    multicolumnListViewCustomAdapter.sortByCustFeedbackAscending();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_multicolumn_list_view_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public OnTouchListener columnContainerOnTouchListener(final LinearLayout column){
        return new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()){
                    column.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(10, 0, 0, 0));
                }else if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()){
                    column.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: line i commented in getView throws Null Pointer Exception.for holder.id

Comment: Can you edit your post and remove all non-relevant code?  There's just too much code to look through.  Also, please attach the actual logcat stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Don't instantiate **mInflater** and **layoutResource** in constructor,
Just try this code in getView() inside if condition as following:

```
mInflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
layoutResource = mInflater.inflate(resId, parent, false);
```

Just remove **final** from

```
final ViewHolder holder;
```

and put it in

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
```

---

Put followin listener

```
holder.column1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    int id = Integer.valueOf((String) holder.id.getText());
                    checkedList.remove(id);
                    checkedList.put(id, isChecked);

                    if(isChecked==false&&checkAllBox.isChecked()){cancelSetCheckedAll=true;checkAllBox.setChecked(false);}
                }
            });
```

outside the if condition.